# Is it possible to change the case on a campaignMemberStatus record

Tags: administration, campaign-member

simple issue3 - user enters campaign member status via the UI with a typo, in this case `Fellow - INterested`, and I need to update it to `Fellow - Interested`.

- update via the UI in 'advanced setup' on campaign : always reverts to INterested
- delete via workbench : reverts to INterested when new member status created
- update via anonymous apex : success, but still is 'INterested'

  - update via anonymous apex to something completely different : success, but new `campaignmemberstatus` reverts to INterested
- bulk api hard delete : success, but new `campaignmemberstatus` reverts to INterested

it appears that it is impossible to change the case of a campaign member status record once inserted.  i have confirmed after deletes that no records are retrieved via SOQL, including deleted records, and have cleared the recycle bin anyways.

am i missing something?  has anyone successfully found a way to do this, or have any insight into why it may not be feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, this is possible.  if you make this change in the setup menu directly, the change will stick.

you can simply edit the existing value, change the case, and hit save.

if your org happens to be like my 10-year-old 30-country 8-language org and have 17576 campaign member status values, be prepared to spend a bit of time finding the right one...

h/t to [Amnon Kruvi](https://twitter.com/kruvman?lang=en) for the tip!